# how to add separator between ul list (jquery ui accordion panel) items?

Tags: html, css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

jQuery UI accordion panel contains list of single line menu items. Menu items needs to grouped.
I tried to add line between menu items using `<hr/>` but line does not appear, empty row appears instead.
How to add line between menu items or other weay to group items without empty line?

```
<a href="#">Panel1</a></h3>
        <ul style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:8px">
         <li ><a href='ref1'>Item1</a></li>
         <li ><a href='ref2'>Item2</a></li>
         <li><hr /></li>
         <li ><a href='ref3'>Item3</a></li>
         <li ><a href='ref3'>Item4</a></li>
..
```

settings used:

```
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        fillSpace: false,
        autoHeight: true,
        navigation: true,
    collapsible: true,
    clearStyle: true
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following ccs code to underline every item:

```
li {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
}
```

The following code can be used to underline only defined items:
**CSS:**

```
li.underline { 
  border-bottom-style: solid; 
  border-bottom-width:1px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="underline">Item</li>
```

Comment: thank you. Separator is required only between some li items. How to apply this style only to some li items ?

Comment: li.underline {
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width:1px;
} then use <li class="underline"> for every list item you want to underline.